# How to get meteor-sharejs documents text

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

I am using [meteor-sharejs](https://github.com/mizzao/meteor-sharejs)

I add the package

```
meteor add mizzao:sharejs-ace
```

Now in my view, i add the document

```
{{> sharejsAce docid="javascriptDoc" id="editor"}}
```

I know that meteor-sharejs creates ops collection and docs.

My Questions is how do i grab the current raw text of  of the "javascriptDoc" document on the server so i send it somewhere else. Like listen for changes and grab that content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to check the ShareJS API for this.

`mizzao:sharejs` is currently using ShareJS 0.6.3; here is the [server API](https://github.com/share/ShareJS/wiki/Server-api). You probably want to use the `getSnapshot` function.

The package makes ShareJS available in `ShareJS.model`, so try `ShareJS.model.getSnapShot(...)` on the server.

*Note: I wrote this package.*

Comment: Thank you getsnapshot does return the current state.

Answer (score 1):

My final solution

```
   Meteor.methods({

    getDocumentText: function () {
        var result = getSnapshotSync('htmlDocumentId');
        return result.snapshot;
    }

});

//create sync method.    
getSnapshotSync = Meteor.wrapAsync(ShareJS.model.getSnapshot)
```